# Selenium in chrome python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

why this script doesn't work

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(
    "https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/?locale=es_ES&response_type=html&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2F")

time.sleep(120)

driver.quit()
```

I want open google chrome and enter in loggin

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description. What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask]